# CSS Grid doesn't break with autofit and causes blowout after adding min-width to a <p>

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I´m new to the grid system but every solution i find is:

```
.c-grid-tmp1 {display:grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr)) ;}
```

It works accordingly and creates a breaking point just like i wanted until i add one line of very important css which is:

```
.c-grid > div > p {min-width:45ch; max-width: 60ch; margin-left:5px}
```

The min-width suddenly causes the breaking point to stop working properly and also causes overlapping and blowout.
At the following screenshots I increasingly reduce the width of the page via chrome devtools.

Normal size

[image: Fullsize]

Stops working properly

[image: Overlap and blowout]

Works properly again

[image: Works properly again]

Then suddenly not again
[image: Then suddenly not again]

And at rly small size

[image: And at rly small size]

```css
section {
  width: 802px;
  background-color:antiquewhite;
}

.c-grid-tmp1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.c-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 60px 1fr;
}

.c-grid>img {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.c-grid>div {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px
}

.c-grid>div>p {
  min-width: 45ch;
  max-width: 60ch;
  margin-left: 5px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Die Vorteile im Einzelnen:</h2>
  <div class="c-grid-tmp1">
    <div class="c-grid">
      <img src="/pics/icon/e-53www-34-grww-000.svg" width="60" height="60" alt="Icon Netzwerk" />
      <div>
        <h4>lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum tenetur, amet deserunt tempore aliquam eos atque distinctio inventore repellendus quaerat! Ducimus laboriosam ut porro amet repudiandae natus ipsam incidunt perferendis!Lorem ipsum dolor
          sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum tenetur, amet deserunt tempore aliquam eos atque distinctio inventore repellendus quaerat! Ducimus laboriosam ut porro amet repudiandae natus ipsam incidunt perferendis!
        </p>
      </div>
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="c-grid">
      <img src="/pics/icon/e-53www-34-grww-000.svg" width="60" height="60" alt="Icon Netzwerk" />
      <div>
        <h4>lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum tenetur, amet deserunt tempore aliquam eos atque distinctio inventore repellendus quaerat! Ducimus laboriosam ut porro amet repudiandae natus ipsam incidunt perferendis! Lorem ipsum dolor
          sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum tenetur, amet deserunt tempore aliquam eos atque distinctio inventore repellendus quaerat! Ducimus laboriosam ut porro amet repudiandae natus ipsam incidunt perferendis!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))` means for *every* 300px, insert a new column. If there is any remaining space (< 300px), expand the columns to fill that space.

With your paragraph being `min-width: 45ch` which is *larger* than 300px (the min column width), there are cases where you'll get a blow out.

You should either:

1. **Remove `min-width: 45ch`** and let the width of your paragraph be decided by the width of it's containing column.
2. **Increase your minimum column width** so that it can never be smaller than your paragraph. For example: `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr))`.

I'd recommend #1, as your column content will resize according to it's column width. Here's a snippet:

```css
section {
  width: 802px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.c-grid-tmp1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.c-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 60px 1fr;
}

.c-grid>img {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.c-grid>div {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px
}

.c-grid>div>p {
  /*min-width: 45ch;*/
  max-width: 60ch;
  margin-left: 5px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Die Vorteile im Einzelnen:</h2>
  <div class="c-grid-tmp1">
    <div class="c-grid">
      <img src="/pics/icon/e-53www-34-grww-000.svg" width="60" height="60" alt="Icon Netzwerk" />
      <div>
        <h4>lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum tenetur, amet deserunt tempore aliquam eos atque distinctio inventore repellendus quaerat! Ducimus laboriosam ut porro amet repudiandae natus ipsam incidunt perferendis!Lorem ipsum dolor
          sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum tenetur, amet deserunt tempore aliquam eos atque distinctio inventore repellendus quaerat! Ducimus laboriosam ut porro amet repudiandae natus ipsam incidunt perferendis!
        </p>
      </div>
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="c-grid">
      <img src="/pics/icon/e-53www-34-grww-000.svg" width="60" height="60" alt="Icon Netzwerk" />
      <div>
        <h4>lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum tenetur, amet deserunt tempore aliquam eos atque distinctio inventore repellendus quaerat! Ducimus laboriosam ut porro amet repudiandae natus ipsam incidunt perferendis! Lorem ipsum dolor
          sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum tenetur, amet deserunt tempore aliquam eos atque distinctio inventore repellendus quaerat! Ducimus laboriosam ut porro amet repudiandae natus ipsam incidunt perferendis!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: that is not rly a satisfying solution as i already knew and included in my post that the error only occurs when i add the min-width: 45ch;. The other suggestions of just increasing the box brought me to the idea to try and match both at a sweetspot between mobile having 2 columns to a certain size. I still hope there is another solution.

Comment: @BlueLovag what kind of soluton are you looking for? it's clear that the issue is the min-width that defeat the 300px value. How you want your elements to behave? they do exactly like the code need them to do

Comment: @TemaniAfif some ppl find workarounds so i would have been ok with a diffrent css approach which gives me the same result as i wanted to have.
for example if minmax(calc(45ch + 60px) 1fr) would have worked for grid.
i accept it though that nobody came up with an idea yet. So i marked it as solution even though he just reversed my error report.

Comment: @BlueLovag *I accept it though that nobody came up with an idea yet* --> it has been only 6h since you asked the question so you can still wait for more idea. Accepting the answer will indeed make people think that you are OK and you are no more looking for different idea where it's not true